# How to generate alphanumeric password in apex controller and display it in visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to auto generate alphanumeric password through apex controller and display this password in visualforce Page. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following piece of code to generate random alphanumeric password using apex :

**APEX :**

```
public class GeneratePasswordController{

public string pwd{get;set;}

     public GeneratePasswordController(){
          Integer len = 10;
          Blob blobKey = crypto.generateAesKey(128);
          String key = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(blobKey);
          pwd = key.substring(0,len);
          System.debug('************ '+pwd);
     }
}
```

**Visualforce Page :**

Use `pwd` string variable in your visualforce page to display

```
<apex:page controller="GeneratePasswordController" >
     <apex:form>
          <apex:outputText value="{!pwd}" />
     </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Refer this : [Apex Crypto class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class)

Comment: i am glad it could help someone :) Don't forget to mark answer as solved as it might be helpful to others !!

Answer (score 1):

You can generate alphanumeric password using below method.Parameter `len` will be the size of the String you want.

```
public class generateRandomString {
public String password{get;set;}
public generateRandomString(){
    password = passwordGenerator(12);
}
public static string passwordGenerator(Integer len) {
    String chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    String[] result = new String[len];
    Integer idx = 0;
    while(idx < len) {
        Integer chr = Math.mod(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger()), 62);
        result[idx++] = chars.substring(chr, chr+1);
    }
    return String.join(result,'');
}}
```

Use password to show on VF page-

```
<apex:outputText value="{!password}" />
```